# Do browsers render canvas elements that are not inside the viewport?

Tags: html, browser, canvas, cpu-usage

I have a page that has pretty heavy (mid-weight rather) `canvas` operations going on. To cater for users on mobile devices and older computers I was thinking I could implement a mechanism that will check if the canvas element is actually visible and decide if the constant calculations and canvas updates (animation running at 30fps) do have to be done or not.

This is working fine, yet when doing a performance test with the Chrome Dev Tools I noticed that even when I disable my visibility check and just let things render all the time the CPU usage of the function in question drops quite a bit when no part of the canvas element(s) is visible (although in theory it should still be performing the same tasks). So: at least on my computer running Chrome 17 it does not make a real difference if I check for the element's actual visibility.

To cut a long story short: Do I need to do this or are browsers smart enough to handle such a case without even telling them (and I can save the visibility checking)?

---

**EDIT**:

So I made some "research" on this topic and built **[this fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/cd9pJ/1/)**

What happens is that it just generates noise at 30 frames per second. Not too pleasing to the eye but, well... The upper part is just a plain `div` to block the viewport. When I scroll down and have the `canvas` element in the viewport CPU Usage tells me it's taking up about 40%, so apparently the browser does have quite a lot to do here. When I scroll back up so that I just have the maroon colored `div` in my viewport and profile the CPU usage it drops to sth around 10%. When I scroll back down: usage goes up again.

So when I implement a visibility check like in this **[modified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FKCLw/2/)**, I do see an increase (a tiny one to be honest) in CPU usage instead of a drop (as it has the additional task of checking if the canvas is inside the viewport).

So I am still wondering if this is some side effect of something that I am not aware of (or I am making some major mistake when profiling) or if I can expect browsers to be smart enough to handle such situations?

If anyone could shed a light on that I'd be very thankful!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you're confused between whether the *logic* is running and whether the *rendering* is happening.  Many browsers now hardware-accelerate their canvases so all rendering happens on the GPU, so actual pixel pushing takes no CPU time anyway.  However your tick function has non-trivial code to generate random noise on the CPU.  So you're only really concerned over whether the tick function is running.  If the canvas is offscreen, it certainly won't be rendered to the display (it's not visible).  As for the canvas draw calls, it probably depends on the browser. It could render all draw calls to an off-screen canvas in case you suddenly scroll it back in to view, or it could just queue up all the draw calls and not actually do anything with them until you scroll the canvas in to view.  I'm not sure what each browser does there.

However, **you shouldn't use `setInterval` or `setTimeout` for animating Canvas**.  Use the new [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.requestAnimationFrame) API.  Browsers don't know what you do in a timer call so will always call the timer.  `requestAnimationFrame` on the other hand is designed specifically for visual things, so the browser has the opportunity to not call the tick function, or to reduce the rate it's called at, if the canvas or page is not visible.

As for how browsers *actually* handle it, I'm not sure.  However, you should definitely prefer it since future browsers may be able to better optimise `requestAnimationFrame` in ways they cannot optimise `setInterval` or `setTimeout`.  I think modern browsers also reduce the ordinary timers to 1 Hz if the page is not visible, but it's definitely much easier for the browser to optimise `requestAnimationFrame`, plus some browsers get you V-syncing and other niceness with it.

So I'm not certain `requestAnimationFrame` will mean your tick function is not called if the canvas is scrolled out of view.  So I'd recommend using *both* `requestAnimationFrame` and the existing visibility check.  That should guarantee you the most efficient rendering.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much for that super thorough answer! I've heard about `requestAnimationFrame` before, but what always bugged me about it is that it seems to aim for animation running at 60fps no matter what (which I do think looks too smooth for many kinds of animation). The only way to limit this I could think of once again included a `setInterval`.... Do you know if there is any way to restrict / alter that?

Comment: Too smooth? I've never heard of an animation that's too smooth, what's wrong with that? :S

Comment: Might sound weird, yet I do have a background in classical animation so I really do think at 12fps, thinking like this is part of my brain by now. My objection might be silly in 95% of the cases, yet for certain cases it would be awesome to have more control.

Comment: OK, well in that case you want to measure delta-time and make stuff happen in a framerate independent way.  requestAnimationFrame runs at V-sync rate so it changes depending on the monitor, so you can't rely on any particular rate there.  Every tick check the time and if enough time has passed since the last tick (e.g. 100ms for 10 fps) then do another tick.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try. Expect Steamboat Willie type of results :)

Comment: Is there any way anyone can think of to detect if the canvas is not rendering because of optimizations?

Answer (score 2):

From my own experience it renders whatever you tell it to render regardless of position on screen.

An example is if you draw tiles, that exceeds the canvas size, you will still see the performance drop unless you optimize the script.

Try your function with a performance demanding animation, and see if you still get the same results.

Comment: The drop in CPU usage seems to happen when the whole `<canvas>` element is scrolled out of display. As you wrote it does not seem to make a difference if you only see 2px height of it or the whole thing.

Comment: That might be the same reason as when you tab out of the website. The browser know's the canvas is not in view and therefor goes into idle mode. Try tabbing away and getting back 5 minutes later and the animation will be roughly where you left it.